# How can I add attribute to product properly?

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute, upgrade-script

I'm trying to add attribute to product entity. It seems that my upgrade script run, because module version is upgraded in `core_resource` table.

However I can't find it at catalog attributes listing.

Upgrade script code:

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
  Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
  'use_discount_label',
  array(
    'label' => 'Use discount label?',
    'default' => '0',
    'group' => 'Other',
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'boolean',
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'unique' => false,
    'filterable' => 1,
    'is_configurable' => false,
    'comparable' => true,
    'filterable_in_search' => false,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
    'searchable' => true,
    'used_for_promo_rules' => false,
    'used_for_sort_by' => true,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'visible' => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
  )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

I'm using Magento EE 1.14.2.2.

Comment: Did you remove the entry for your module from `core_resource` and try again?

Comment: I downgrade it every time, from 0.0.2 to 0.0.1 and then refresh, is that procedure ok for testing?

Comment: Yes that is okay if your filename is `upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php`

Comment: Yes, my file has exactly that name

Comment: Please check if you get your attribute in `eav_attribute` table

Comment: Yes it's in this table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup script looks correct, Try removing attribute before creating it. downgrade entry from `core_resource` and run the script again.

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product','use_discount_label');
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
  Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
  'use_discount_label',
  array(
    'label' => 'Use discount label?',
    'default' => '0',
    'group' => 'Other',
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'boolean',
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'unique' => false,
    'filterable' => 1,
    'is_configurable' => false,
    'comparable' => true,
    'filterable_in_search' => false,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
    'searchable' => true,
    'used_for_promo_rules' => false,
    'used_for_sort_by' => true,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'visible' => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
  )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```